# A double preceding function with bug

Tags: python

It is a homework question that I am stuck on:

Your classmate claims to have written a function that replaces each value in a list with twice the preceding value (and the first value with 0). For example, if the list [1, 3, 7, 11] is passed as a parameter, the function is supposed to return [0, 2, 6, 14] -- Note: 22 is not part of the output. Here's the code:

```
def double_preceding(values): 
    if (values != []): 
        temp = values[0] 
    values[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, len(values)): 
        values[i] = 2 * temp 
        temp = values[i]
```

Analyse this function and rewrite it so that it works as intended.

I couldn't even follow what the code was doing, can someone explain to me please

Comment: What part are you confused about?

Comment: First of all, indent the code correctly. It's essential in Python.

Comment: my analysis would be to throw away that code and just `return [0] + [2*x for x in values[:-1]]`, but that's maybe not the spirit of the exercise...

Comment: @OozeMeister I got confused starting at the for loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I guessed the indentation of the program correctly. See comments below:

**Code:**

```
def double_preceding(v):
    values = v[:] # Make a copy of the list passed as argument

    if (values != []): # If list is not empty, store the first value in 'temp'
        temp = values[0]
    else:
        return

    v[0] = 0 # Set the first value of the list as '0' (as the problem says it)

    for i in range(1, len(values)): # Iterate 'n - 1' times, where n is the length of the list
        v[i] = 2 * temp # Set the corresponding value to twice the precedent (the precedent is stored in 'temp')
        temp = values[i]
```

**Test:**

```
v = [1, 3, 7, 11]
double_preceding(v)
print v
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 2, 6, 14, 22]
```

Comment: Your sample output is wrong, it should not include the 22 at the end.

Comment: Also, you don't handle empty lists correctly (you'll raise an exception from `v[0] = 0`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation of the given code, and the errors I see within it:

```
def double_preceding(values): 
    if (values != []):    # this if checks for an empty list, to avoid exceptions
        temp = values[0] 
    values[0] = 0  # but this line is not indented, so you may get an IndexError anyway
    for i in range(1, len(values)): # this loops over all indexes but the first (0)
        values[i] = 2 * temp  # this replaces the current value with double temp
        temp = values[i] # this line however saves the same doubled value as the new temp
```

So, the two errors I see is incorrect handling of empty lists, and a logic error in the assignment code that will cause the loop to replace values after the first with the list's original first value times successive powers of two.

A good way to solve the second issue is to do both of the assignments in the loop with a single statement. This is a neat thing that Python can do that many other languages cannot. Here's what a basic version would look like:

```
 values[i], temp = temp*2, values[i]
```

The commas are the key things to pay attention to. The one on the right side of the assignment makes a `tuple` out of `temp*2` and `values[i]`. The comma on the left hand side tells Python to unpack the tuple being assigned into the variables `values[i]` and `temp`. And the two parts are evaluated in that order (first the expression on the right side, then the unpacking and assignments). This means that the "old" values of `temp` and `values[i]` are used to build the tuple and it doesn't matter that they're both reassigned later.

If we're doing the assignments that way, we can solve the empty list situation elegantly too. Rather than treating the first value specially and needing a check to make sure `values[0]` is a valid expression, why not just set `temp` to `0` at the start and let the loop handle the first value as well as the later ones? Here's a fully fixed function:

```
def double_preceeding(values):
    temp = 0
    for i in range(len(values)): # loop over all indexes, not skipping the first
        values[i], temp = temp*2, values[i]
```

The loop will do nothing if `values` is an empty list, since `len([])` is 0 and `range(0)` is empty itself.

Example output:

```
>>> L=[]
>>> double_preceeding(L)
>>> L
[]
>>> L=[1, 3, 7, 11]
>>> double_preceeding(L)
>>> L
[0, 2, 6, 14]
```